# When importing a style via SLD in GeoServer and previewing it, there is an issue with the Chinese legend names displaying as garbled characters

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld, windows, encoding

When I use an SLD file exported from QGIS to create a new style in GeoServer and then preview the style, there is an issue with the legend name displaying as garbled characters.
QGIS windows as follows.

[image]

The appearance after importing into GeoServer is as follows (I simplified the SLD for a complete view).

[image]

However, when I open the WMS service in ArcGIS Pro, the legend display is normal, as shown in the following image.
[image]
I would like to know why the Chinese labels for the symbol system are garbled during preview, but the legend in the service appears normal.
SLD content follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.1.0" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>样式测试</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>样式测试</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>冰川及永久积雪</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>冰川及永久积雪</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>ejlmc</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>冰川及永久积雪</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#d7191c</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce on my machine, can you add some details of how you upload the file, what your operating system is

Comment: Thank you for your attention to my question. I am using the Windows 10 Professional edition system, Geoserver version 2.23.2. My SLD file was exported in QGIS 3.28.9, and I imported it through the GeoServer style interface to create a new style.

Comment: I also would like to know what system you are using. Do you encounter garbled characters when previewing the symbol system? By garbled characters, I mean that the displayed Chinese characters do not match the ones I have configured.

Comment: I'm using Linux and have my system set to use UTF-8 by default - I get exactly the same characters in the legend as in the SLD file.

Comment: I changed the encoding of the Windows system to UTF-8, and now Chinese characters display correctly. However, this configuration currently affects the usage of other software. For example, when I create a Chinese folder in NFS without configuring UTF-8, it displays as garbled text.

Comment: then you need to convert the sld file to your normal encoding - that's something someone who uses windows may be able to help with

Comment: So, does this kind of issue belong to a bug in GeoServer? After all, I installed the Windows version of GeoServer, so theoretically, it should be compatible with this issue, haha.

Comment: You're very welcome! Grateful hearts for your testing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your system is running with a default encoding that is not UTF-8 but that QGIS saves the file with a UTF-8 encoding. So GeoServer uses the default encoding and not the UTF-8 that QGIS intended.

> I changed the encoding of the Windows system to UTF-8, and now Chinese characters display correctly. However, this configuration currently affects the usage of other software. For example, when I create a Chinese folder in NFS without configuring UTF-8, it displays as garbled text.

The solution is to configure QGIS to use your default encoding or convert the file to UTF-8 before uploading it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Ian Turton's response, here I'd like to add how to modify the encoding on a Windows system.
The specific steps are as follows: Control Panel -> Clock and Region -> Region -> Administrative -> Change system locale... -> Check 'Beta... UTF-8...' as shown in the screenshot below.
[image]